# How to model dependent and nested sum types?

Tags: types, enums, rust

I'm wondering how one would organize the following kind of data, especially in Rust, but answers in any programming language are interesting.

My system processes requests of several types each with different data associated, e.g.

```
enum Request {
    A(i64),
    B(f64),
    C(String),
}
```

If a processed request is approved, we need to store the request along with data about the approval process, but the kind of data depends on the type. So I want to say

```
enum ApprovedRequest {
    ApprovedA(Request::A, i64),
    ApprovedB(Request::B, f64),
    ApprovedC(Request::C, String),
}
```

On the other hand, it might get denied and then different information would be appended, so I want to say

```
enum DeniedRequest {
    DeniedA(Request::A, String),
    DeniedB(Request::B, String),
    DeniedC(Request::C, i64),
}
```

This isn't valid Rust, because Request::A is not a type. [See issue 754.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/754) I think the way I've presented the problem would be a use case for dependent types. But anyway, any suggestion for how to organize this, in Rust or another language with pattern matching?

Comment: Please use `rustfmt` to format your snippets. This is much better to read and one instantly knows what you want the enums are.

Comment: @hellow, sounds good, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, my go-to solution is creating independent types and wrapping them in the enum:

```
struct A(i64);
struct B(f64);
struct C(String);

enum Request {
    A(A),
    B(B),
    C(C),
}
```

There is a bit of repetition involved, but it's otherwise fairly simple. The names need not match, either.

---

With this in place, expressing `ApprovedRequest` and `DeniedRequest` is immediately possible.

*Another* possibility, though, is to use traits and generics:

```
trait Approved {
    type Payload;
}

struct ApprovedT<T: Approved> {
    request: T,
    approval: T::Payload,
}

enum ApprovedRequest {
    A(ApprovedT<A>),
    B(ApprovedT<B>),
    C(ApprovedT<C>),
}
```

And then, per request, explain the payload:

```
impl Approved for A {
    type Payload = i64;
}

impl Denied for A {
    type Payload = String;
}
```

The main benefit of this approach is that any method that needs to manipulate an approved request and its approval payload can be made generic on `ApprovedT`, as otherwise, what would be the type of the payload?

---

> I think the way I've presented the problem would be a use case for dependent types.

Careful; *Dependent Typing* is a concept of Computer Science generally understood to linking run-time values to types.

For example, the following would require dependent types as a run-time value ends up being used in a type definition:

```
//  Not valid Rust.
fn create_array(n: usize) -> [u8; n];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! To explain my dependent types comment, ApprovedRequest could be a dependent sum type, i.e. a pair (x: Request, y: ??) where the type of y depends on the runtime value of x, for example, if x is Request::A then y: i64, but if x is Request::B, then y: f64.

Comment: In a language supporting dependent types, possibly. Rust does not support them for now, and there is no known plan to add them for now.